# How can i use Apache ANT Programmatically

Tags: java, ant

I'm making a simple program that compile and make a jar file but i don't want to use a build.xml (and then invoke it with exec).

but i want using ANT API(for example:`org.apache.tools.ant.Task`)

Any Help?

Comment: Good luck. Whenever I wanted to use ant programmatically I eventually gave up...

Answer (score 3):

You might as well get the answer directly from the source: [Using Ant Tasks Outside of Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/antexternal.html)

You might also be interested in something like [Leafcutter](http://java.net/projects/leafcutter), which claims to provide:

> An API which allows you to execute Ant tasks from Java code.

I haven't used it personally, just letting you know that it exists...

Comment: The Leafcutter link is broken.