# Using Apache Ant APIs in Java program to programmatically build source files

Tags: java, apache, api, ant, build-automation

I am looking for good and practical resources that will help me use the Ant APIs effectively. The project website just gives the documentation of the API which is not useful at all. Very few websites seem to give very brief tutorials on the subject.

Is there some resource I am missing out on? How can I use the Ant APIs for simple tasks, without spending hours browsing through them and looking at source code?

Thanks.

(Answers to previously asked questions not helpful - [How can i use Apache ANT Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085002/how-can-i-use-apache-ant-programmatically) )

Comment: Can you tell us, why the previous answers did not help, so we can look in the right direction.

Comment: @nfechner: None of the resources led to even a basic explanation of the API or a guide on how to use it. The two examples presented are very isolated in their application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, the lack of good resources on using the Ant API, is known and intended.
The bottom paragraph of [this](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) article from the Ant says -

*The question you are probably asking yourself at this point is: How would I know which classes and methods have to be called in order to set up a dummy Project and Target? The answer is: you don't. Ultimately, you have to be willing to get your feet wet and read the source code. The above example is merely designed to whet your appetite and get you started. Go for it!*

So this seems to be the only way to make best use of the API.

Answer (score 2):

> ..Java program to programmatically build source files

If compiling/Jarring is all you need and you can run it in an SDK (as opposed to a plain JRE), look to the [JavaCompiler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) class for compilation.  Then use the Jar related classes to build the Jars.

All J2SE.  Ant not included, Ant not required.

Answer (score 0):

There is no better manual to understand ANT than : http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html

I am not sure if you've gone through [this](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) link that explains in detail about creating a task. A word of caution, If you're new to ANT, there is no easy way to jump on this tutorial. Better to learn the basics before you come here. Refer above link for a good starting point.